# ui-router not rendering view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have something odd, probably missed some trivial step along the way.  In the console
I have the following...

```
$stateChangeStart to undefined- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : 
 [object Object] [object Object]
   "$stateChangeStart to undefined- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : 
"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      controller: "DashboardController",
      controllerAs: "vm",
      name: "dashboard",
      resolve: { },
      settings: { },
      templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.html",
      title: "dashboard",
      url: "/"
   }
   {
  [functions]: ,
  __proto__: { }
   }

   $viewContentLoading - view begins loading - dom not rendered [object Object]
   "$viewContentLoading - view begins loading - dom not rendered"
   {
  [functions]: ,
  __proto__: { },
   async: true,
  controller: null,
  locals: { },
  notify: true,
  params: { },
  template: null,
  view: { }
   }

$stateChangeSuccess to dashboard- fired once the state transition is complete.
```

The $stateChangeStart has the view, but by the time it gets to $viewContentLoading its gone.  Needless to say, by view is not getting loaded.

Here is the stub from the route loader

```
        {
            state: 'dashboard',
            config: {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                title: 'dashboard',
                settings: {
                    nav: 1,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard'
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using the following module for routing

```
    /* Help configure the state-base ui.router */
    (function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('blocks.router')
    .provider('routerHelper', routerHelperProvider);

routerHelperProvider.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
/* @ngInject */
function routerHelperProvider($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var config = {
        docTitle: undefined,
        resolveAlways: {}
    };

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    this.configure = function(cfg) {
        angular.extend(config, cfg);
    };

    this.$get = RouterHelper;
    RouterHelper.$inject = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$state', 'logger'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function RouterHelper($location, $rootScope, $state, logger) {
        var handlingStateChangeError = false;
        var hasOtherwise = false;
        var stateCounts = {
            errors: 0,
            changes: 0
        };

        var service = {
            configureStates: configureStates,
            getStates: getStates,
            stateCounts: stateCounts
        };

        init();

        return service;

        ///////////////

        function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
            states.forEach(function(state) {
                state.config.resolve =
                    angular.extend(state.config.resolve || {}, config.resolveAlways);
                $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
            });
            if (otherwisePath && !hasOtherwise) {
                hasOtherwise = true;
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(otherwisePath);
            }
        }

        function handleRoutingErrors() {
            // Route cancellation:
            // On routing error, go to the dashboard.
            // Provide an exit clause if it tries to do it twice.
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
                function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
                    if (handlingStateChangeError) {
                        return;
                    }
                    stateCounts.errors++;
                    handlingStateChangeError = true;
                    var destination = (toState &&
                        (toState.title || toState.name || toState.loadedTemplateUrl)) ||
                        'unknown target';
                    var msg = 'Error routing to ' + destination + '. ' +
                        (error.data || '') + '. <br/>' + (error.statusText || '') +
                        ': ' + (error.status || '');
                    logger.warning(msg, [toState]);
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            );
        }

        function init() {
            handleRoutingErrors();
            updateDocTitle();
        }

        function getStates() { return $state.get(); }

        function updateDocTitle() {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    stateCounts.changes++;
                    handlingStateChangeError = false;
                    var title = config.docTitle + ' ' + (toState.title || '');
                    $rootScope.title = title; // data bind to <title>
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
})();
```